# python uses system cpu time when consuming memory

Tags: python, numpy, cpu-usage

I noticed that when python (may be just `numpy`?) are taking up memory, system cpu time become significant.

For example, when running the following code (`numpy` multithreading is disabled):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(50, 50, 1000000)
```

About 88% of the running core is devoted to user time and 12% to system time.

However, when running the following code:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    a = np.random.rand(50, 50)
```

All cpu time are devoted to user time.

I want to understand:

(1) why this happens?

(2) Do I need to profile my code to use less memory? Notice that when I say profiling, I don't care about memory, and walltime is the only thing I care. I am just worrying that too much system time is slowing down my program.

Comment: Is the total processing usage also greater as well? You question implies such.

Comment: No, I did not compare them since the two code snippets are not doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing code:

```
N=10000000
M=10

# Method 1
a=[]
for i in range(N):
    a.append(np.random.rand(M,M))

# Method 2
a = np.random.rand(M,M,N)

# Method 3
for i in range(N):
    a = np.random.rand(M,M)
```

Results by linux `time` command:
[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj2PF.png)

and also:

```
Method 3 at M=10 and N=10000000
real  0m15.221s
user  0m15.169s
sys   0m0.016s
```

Results shows that system call time decreases as block size increases in method 1, and will finally goes to the same level as in method 2. Meanwhile the proportion of time cost of system call decreases as block size goes smaller, due to a more rapid growth of user-space time cost.

As for method 3, it left out the expense on allocating large amount of memory, resulting in an extreme tiny cost on system calls, which is basically unreal in your program (I know what it does!).